# A script that download a file and rename

Tags: download

I'm facing an little issue here. At the place I live, they shape the download speed by extension (using delaypool). Is there any script that I can run on my web that will let me enter the URL of files that I wanted to download, then it will download the file and rename it to "originalfilename.abc" (because .abc is not shaped)then save it on my web where I can download it. By the way, I have a paid webhosting service.

Thanks

---

I tried the SSH (my web hosting does indeed provide me with shell access) but all I get is a blank page in my browser. No error. Please advice.

Also, reason I choose script on the server instead of SSH because I though that SSH would be slower than direct HTTP download from my webserver. Can anyone point that out if I'm right or wrong with my thinking.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can write a vbs script or even batch file script that will go to a designated URL, and then download the file, then rename it. Then you can script FTP commands to upload to your webhosting service (I'm sure it has an FTP site for access). You could load this as a scheduled task, or run it manually.

I'd do either one of these routes.

Comment: I'm sorry that I haven't been clear with my question. I would like the the script to be on the webhosting service so that the webserver will download the file from given URL and save it on the webserver. Then I will download the renamed file off my webhosting server. 

Hope that is a bit clearer

Answer (score 0):

A simpler (once its set up anyway ;) option I can think of is going through a secure tunnel. Whilst this is not quite answering your question I believe this to be simpler while achieving the same thing.

Get an SSH Client ([Putty](http://www.putty.org/)) and get a free Proxy. If your web-server has an SSH-server you can use it as Proxy as well of course, I am using my modified router at home as proxy via DynDns, but the Tor-Network will work, if very slow, so do other official free and paid proxy servers. If you are using an application to download that does not have the option to specify a proxy, get [Proxifier Portable](http://www.proxifier.com/).

Use Putty to create the tunnel. Here some how-tos:

- http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html
- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/security/use-putty-as-a-secure-proxy-on-windows/421
- http://kimmo.suominen.com/docs/proxy-through-ssh/

And set your application to use your proxy (or actually to use putty which connects via SSH to your proxy) by entering 127.0.0.1:1080 into the proxy settings. Alternatively, if the app does not have an option to enter proxy settings, add 127.0.0.1:1080 to your Proxifier proxy list and add the applications that are supposed to use that connection to Proxifier.

Now you can do pretty much everything without anyone eavesdropping your connection stream being able to tell what it is, as the connection stream is SSH encrypted. This includes surfing websites that your provider/company/mother has blocked, download anything - even if blocked by IP/name/whatever-filters and even play MMORPGs from work (something which I do not recommend because it will get you fired and there is always some way for someone to figure it out, just saying it is possible to do even in secured company/school networks as Port 22 (SSH) is usually one of the 2 Ports which are open on pretty much any network (the other one being port 80)).

Its a wee bit of a pain to set up. Once it is working though, you can even put it on a usb-stick and use it pretty much anywhere as long as you remember what proxy to connect to. And you wont have to rewrite scripts to try to circumvent the delaypool thingy.